# Overidding library function in es6

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, babeljs, html-framework-7

I'm trying to override specific function in a library.
In my case, I'm trying to override some functions on [Framework7](http://framework7.io). The library simply has class called `Framework7`, in non ES6 javascript, creating instance of application would look like this:

```
var app = new Framework7();
```

so I assume it's extendable, so here my code to extends it:

```
export class Application extends Framework7 {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
}
```

the code run fine, however, when I try to override one of the function, let say `showPreloader`, the function itself is never called

```
export class Application extends Framework7 {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    showPreloader(title) {
        console.log('this not printed :(');
        super(title); // this is not called as well

        // but showPreloader() from Framework7 still called
    }
}
```

I also try different approach to override it, i come with a solution like this:

```
export class Application extends Framework7 {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);

        this.showPreloader = (title) => {
            console.log('print me!'); // printed! :D
            super(); // oh, wait! cannot call super from here! :(
        }
    }
}
```

However, it looks a bit ugly and I cannot call super from there.

Is there any workaround so I can override a function from library and calling the base function via `super` (or anything?)

Comment: No, that's just how overwriting instance-specific methods works. You can call the "super" method by storing the original in a variable before overwriting it and doing old-school `.call(this)`

Comment: Doesn't look like the library is putting those methods on the prototype - they're directly assigning them to the function instance - so you would need to override these on a function-by-function basis instead of prototypal inheritance

Comment: @Bergi is it something like the last approach that i describe in my post? but save the `this.showPreloader` to a variable and `.call()` it on the overridden function?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I'm not quite sure what exactly you mean by "override these on a function-by-function basis". Perhaps you can answer this question with some example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume it's extendable

Don't. Read the docs, ask the authors, or read the source yourself.

In your case, the library you've chosen doesn't exactly follow best practises, it just [installs its methods](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/blob/79ca59bbbed5a9e67c9243ae4e1dfc51661e3630/src/js/modals.js#L155) directly on the [`app` "instance"](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/blob/79ca59bbbed5a9e67c9243ae4e1dfc51661e3630/src/js/f7-intro.js#L7). It's a [factory function](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/blob/79ca59bbbed5a9e67c9243ae4e1dfc51661e3630/src/js/f7-outro.js#L2), not a constructor.

> Is there any workaround so I can override a function from library and calling the base function?

Yes, by storing the original method in a variable before overwriting it. You then can call it using `.call(this)` (like inheritance was done in ES5).

```
…
    const original = this.showPreloader;
    this.showPreloader = (title) => {
        console.log('print me!'); // printed! :D
        original.call(this, title);
    }
```

However, that's no fun, especially since it's not just a few instance-specific methods but actually all of them. So you'd better drop ES6 `class` syntax and "subclassing" here, and use a parasitical inheritance approach instead:

```
function MyFramework7(options) {
    const app = new Framework7(options);
    const {showPreloader, …} = app; // all the original methods
    … // mess with the object to your liking
    return app;
}
```

Or maybe you don't even need to wrap it in a function, as `app` is a singleton I guess.

Comment: about your last sentence.. you mean wrapping the library object in the class? so I get something like `getFramework7()` or something?

Comment: @ChronoCross: I've clarified it a bit